# How can I unit test isolated scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test a simple directive but the variable in the scope is always undefined.

Directive Src Code:

```
.directive('ratingButton', ['$rootScope',


function($rootScope) {
      return {
          restrict: "E",
          replace: true,
          template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-circle" ng-class="getRatingClass()"></button>',
          scope: {
              buttonRating: "="
          },
          link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
              scope.getRatingClass = function() {
                  if (!scope.buttonRating)
                      return '';
                  else if (scope.buttonRating.toUpperCase() === 'GREEN')
                      return 'btn-success';
                  else if (scope.buttonRating.toUpperCase() === 'YELLOW')
                      return 'btn-warning warning-text';
                  else if (scope.buttonRating.toUpperCase() === 'RED')
                      return 'btn-danger';
                  else if (scope.buttonRating.toUpperCase() === 'BLUE')
                      return 'btn-info';
              }
          }
      };
  }])
```

Test:

```
describe('Form Directive: ratingButton', function() {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('dashboardApp'));

    var scope,
        element;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        //set our view html.
        element = angular.element('<rating-button button-rating="green"></rating-button>');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should return appropriate class based on rating', function() {
        //console.log(element.isolateScope());
        expect(element.isolateScope().buttonRating).toBe('green');
        expect(element.isolateScope().getRatingClass()).toBe('btn-success');

    });

});
```

I used similar code in another directive unit test I had by passing values through element attributes and it worked as expected. For this test buttonRating is always undefined not sure where to go from here(I am fairly new with Jasmine/Karma)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of setting string `green` set it on the scope bound when the directive element is compiled in your startup of the test. Otherwise it will look for the value of scope property with the name `green` on the bound scope, and which of course is not defined in your case.

i.e `scope.buttonRating = 'green';`

and

`angular.element('<rating-button button-rating="buttonRating"></rating-button>')`

Try:

```
  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.buttonRating = 'green'; //<-- Here
        //set our view html.
        element = angular.element('<rating-button button-rating="buttonRating"></rating-button>');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should return appropriate class based on rating', function() {
        expect(element.isolateScope().buttonRating).toBe('green');
        expect(element.isolateScope().getRatingClass()).toBe('btn-success');

    });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X8n9KlybeKOnG2jtWIvR?p=preview)**

Comment: ah looks like that worked. no idea why I didn't think of that!

Comment: ugh, wasted so much time on this. worked fine for @ but = didn't realize you can't put the literal string in there (it is UNBINDABLE). glad Angular 2 is getting rid of 2 way binding under the hood.

Comment: good way of testing is not setting the variable but quote the string literal   ('<rating-button button-rating="\'buttonRating\'"></rating-button>')

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isolateScope' of undefined" on this Plunker. Same when I am using this code on my local.